# mplfinance add_plot 'Unrecognized kwarg="zorder"'

Tags: plot, mplfinance

Like the title, when I want add multiple lines to a single axes,, I need to put a customized zorder, this is very helpful to make the plot better look, but I get error:
**

> 'Unrecognized kwarg="zorder"'

**

The parameter was supported by matplotlib, but seems not available from mplfinance, does anyone know it?

Please refer bellow:

```
            for i,line in enumerate(my_columns):
                zorder = zorder_list[i]
                ap = mpf.make_addplot(tmp[line], ax=ax, zorder=zorder)
```

Answer (score 2):

`zorder` is not yet supported in mplfinance.

There is an enhancement request for it:
https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/311

Do to other priorities, `zorder` implementation in mplfinance has been pushed off for the time being.  If you are interested in contributing this enhancement to mplfinance, I will be happy to guide you through the process and through the code.

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of mplfinance.

---

As a work-around (in the meantime) the following *might* work:

```py
ap = []
for i,line in enumerate(my_columns):
    ax.zorder = zorder_list[i]
    ap.append(mpf.make_addplot(tmp[line], ax=ax))
```

however it seems to me that, unless you are using a different `ax` variable for each `make_addplot()` then ultimately all of the `addplot` lines will have the same zorder, however even if so, they can have a different zorder than the main portion of the plot, assuming that `ax` is a different Axes than is used by the main portion of the plot.

Comment: hi, thanks Daniel, just to clarify that I am trying to plot multi-lines into a same ax, base on my observasion, it will make a default zorder according with the adding sequence. I will take a look into it and see if I can make a path.